# Supporting messagePack protocol in Serverless Azure SignalR services

Tags: azure-functions, signalr, signalr-hub, azure-signalr

**Note: this is not a duplicate question despite some similarities.**

Microsoft recently started supporting `messagePack` protocol when the transport type's mode is `Persistent` [per this article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/blob/dev/docs/management-sdk-guide.md#transport-type).

The challenge is that the Azure Function App supporting the backend uses the following pattern to send out a message to a group of users or a user:

```cs
[Function("sendMessage")]
    [SignalROutput(HubName = "myhub")]
    public static async Task<SignalRMessageAction> SendMsgAsync(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = $"v1/{groupId}")]
        HttpRequestData req,
        string groupId,
        FunctionContext context)
    {

        var message = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        return new("message")
        {
            GroupName = groupId,
            Arguments = new[] { message }
        };
    }
```

There is no place in our function app host builder or configuration to make it leverage messagePack protocol. I can understand that [the mentioned article]((https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/blob/dev/docs/management-sdk-guide.md#transport-type) applies to ASP.NET core configuration but our function app's architecture is solely designed for a serverless environment.

I'm not sure if instantiating `ServiceManagerBuilder` and passing its instance around through dependency injection is a great idea for our case. If that's the only option, it will introduce a lot of code changes and architecture changes in our code which is not desired and ideal.